# Как привязать домен к NodeJS на DigitalOcean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, nextjs

У меня приложение разделено на фронт и бек части
Фронт часть у меня работает на NextJS и хранится на хостинге Versel, бек на NodeJS и лежит на Digitalocean

Я купил домен, привязал его к фронту, но сейчас мой node работает на http и фронт часть запрещает запросы, а чтобы подключить ssl к node для него нужен домен

Вопрос смогу ли я создать субдомен моего основного домена и привязать его к NodeJS

Comment: https://cloudsupport.digitalocean.com/s/   у Digitalocean есть центр поддержки, вы пробовали связаться с ними?

Comment: @DovgalDima не пробовал, просто думал решение может быть просто, не хотел тратить много времени, но спасибо за ответ